# Advance Scripting inside a DockerFile

Tags: python, rest, docker

I am trying to create a Docker image/container that will run on Windows 10/Linux and test a REST API. Is it possible to embed the function (from my `.bashrc` file) inside the DockerFile? The function `pytest` calls `pylint` before running the .py file. If the rating is not 10/10, then it prompts the user to fix the code and exits. This works fine on Linux.

Basically here is the pseudo-code inside the DockerFile I am attempting to build an image.

```
------------------------------------------
From: Ubuntu x.xx
install python
Install pytest
install pylint
copy test_file to the respective folder
Execute pytest test_file_name.py
if the rating is not 10\10:
    prompt the user to resolve the rating issue and exit
```

```
------------here is the partial code snippet from the func------------------------
function pytest () {
    argument1="$1"
    # Extract the path and file name for pylint when method name is passed
    pathfilename=`echo ${argument1} | sed 's/::.*//'`
    clear && printf '\e[3J'
    output=$(docker exec -t orch-$USER pylint -r n ${pathfilename})
    if (echo "$output" | grep 'warning.*error' o&>/dev/null or
        echo "${output}" | egrep 'warning|convention' &>/dev/null)
    then
            echo echo "${output}" | sed 's/\(warning\)/\o033[33m\1\o033[39m/;s/\(errors\|error\)/\o033[31m\1\o033[39m/'
            YEL='\033[0;1;33m'
            NC='\033[0m'
            echo -e "\n  ${YEL}Fix module as per pylint/PEP8 messages to achieve 10/10 rating before pusing to github\n${NC}"`
fi
```

Another option I can think of:
Step 1] Build the image (using DockerFile) with all the required software
Step 2] In a .py file, add the call for execution of `pytest` with the logic from the function.

Your thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can turn that function into a standalone shell script.  (Pretty much by just removing the `function` wrapper, and taking out the `docker exec` part of the tool invocation.)  Once you've done that, you can `COPY` the shell script into your image, and once you've done that, you can `RUN` it.

```
...
COPY pylint-enforcer.sh .
RUN chmod +x ./pylint-enforcer.sh \
 && ./pylint-enforcer.sh
...
```

It looks like [pylint will produce a non-zero exit code if it emits any messages](https://pylint.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/run.html#exit-codes).  For purposes of a Dockerfile, it may be enough to just `RUN pylint -r -n .`; if it prints anything, it looks like it will return a non-zero exit code, which `docker build` will interpret as "failure" and not proceed.

You might consider whether you'll ever want the ability to build and push an image of code that isn't absolutely perfect (during a production-down event, perhaps), and whether you want to require root-level permissions to run simple code-validity tools (if you can `docker` anything you can edit arbitrary files on the host as root).  I'd suggest running these tools out of a non-Docker virtual environment during your CI process, and neither place them in your Dockerfile nor depend on `docker exec` to run them.